# Read from ADLS gen 2 with SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis, etl, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

Does anyone know which connection and Data Flow Component to use for ADLS (Azure Data Lake Store) gen2?

I've managed to use the blob connector in the connection manager and successfully connect to ADLS Gen2, but when I try to use the blob source component I get a 400 bad request. Works fine if it's just a blob storage without HNS.

The ADLS components states it's just for ADLS gen 1.

So how to read and write to/from ADLS Gen 2?

Comment: "Blob storage APIs aren't yet available to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 accounts." Source: [Known issues with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues). The preferred way is to [Copy data to or from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A current version of SSIS Azure Feature Pack supports ADLS Gen2. It can be used as a data source or destination in dataflow:

[image]

The screenshot is to show it as a destination, but the ADLSgen2 works well also as a source via corresponding "Flexible File Destination" and "Flexible File Source"

[image]

Comment: Useful update @AlexanderVolok.  There wasn't much fanfare over this release of the feature pack, possibly they are pushing Azure Data Factory Gen 2 more now.

Comment: Thanks, they do, by doing small and modest steps. What is available for ADLS gen2 is: data sources, destinations, file copy and foreach item iterator

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, based on the [great link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues) provided by **@rickvdbosch** it looks like that there are many temporary limitations with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 concerning the BLOB Storage API. Which means that it is not a component limitation and maybe you should wait until it will be integrated with SSIS.*

## Microsoft SQL SERVER Feature pack for Azure

If you meant these components when you mentioned that:

> The ADLS components states it's just for ADLS gen 1.

***Then ignore this part.***

I am not pretty sure if it supports Gen2, but I think you can use the `Azure Data Lake Store` components which are a part of the **Microsoft SQL SERVER feature pack for Azure**. For more information you can refer to:

- [Azure Data Lake Store in SSIS](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2017/08/azure-data-lake-store-in-ssis.html?m=1)
- [Azure Data Lake Store Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-data-lake-store-source?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Azure Data Lake Store Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-data-lake-store-destination?view=sql-server-2017)

**Download Link**

- [Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-2017)

---

## Other methods

If the suggestion above didn't work then you should use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage) or a command line by [Installing AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html) and [using AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) v10

Answer (score 0):

I got the following info:
"At the moment Gen 2 don’t support BLOB API (but it will in a short time) and hence, SSIS is not able to connect."

So for SSIS it's currently either ADLS Gen 1, or blob store

Answer (score 0):

I used the Script Task to write files or System.Objects (converted to csv in Memory) to Azure Storage Gen 2 (Hierarchical Namespace Enabled) using the Rest API. I did this as a demo until the SSIS components are released.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to ADLS Gen2 using the old components from the Azure Feature Pack, but you can connect to the blob Gen2 (non-hierarchical) using the Azure Blob Destination Component.

[image]

Comment: It is very important the comment "non-hierarchical". Unfortunately this is a big flaw because hierarchical namespace is extremely useful in enterprise-scale applications. I wonder when they are going to support that as well